# Custom UIActivity with the built-in Mail appearance

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I wish to use a UIActivityController with the standard activities to share a UIImage. However when the user selects Mail I'd like to do my own logic: present a form to let the user select a few options, and then compose the email myself so that I can add my own body and attachments to the email.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I understand that I can create a custom UIActivity, but then I'll have to provide a custom image which will be displayed in gray, and the standard Mail icon would be much more recognizable.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14619802/341994

Comment: For IOS8 apple have allowed custom UIActivites to use colored icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize the built-in UIActivities such as (email, Twitter, Facebook).

You can only customize the items to be shared on those channels.